# Disable ECDHE cipher in SslSocket in .NET Core

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, wireshark

My .NET Core program uses SslStream for encrypted socket communications between Windows servers.  I want to use Wireshark, and gave it my certificate file, but Wireshark is unable to decrypt the packets because it's using an ECDME cypher suite (TLS_ECDME_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384).  I've found numerous sites that explain how to disable ECDME cypher suites in IIS and several browsers, but that doesn't apply here.  How do I get SslStream in .NET Core to not use an ECDME cypher suite?  One thing I should mention is that I use Remote Desktop to access these servers, so I can't disable something at the server level that could hinder RDP.